# Magento: url rewrites - category page error

Tags: php, magento

I'm using URL rewrites to keep nice SEO and user friendly links.
Lately I've noticed strange error:
at category pages (and only there) Magento keeps to ignore rewritings and display links as:

```
/catalog/product/view/id/17/s/category/8/
```

in navigation, footer etc. I'm out of ideas... rewrite index was refreshed serval times.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error here please, it will tell us more about the problem. Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: The page looks fine, but link is not user friendly ;-) that's the 'error'